# Google Map not rendered again - after pointing to load resources from rawgit it worked only for a week or so

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I have my app using `gmaps4rails` working for a while after Google moved to `GIT`.

Here is what I am using in the `application.htm.erb`

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&amp;libraries=geometry;&amp;key=AIzaSyAncOJnAgKEjrv2PY__Z0gYy3zJyTznUQ0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/gh-pages/src/richmarker-compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in the `Gemfile` I have these lines

```
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
```

In the `application.js` I have this line

```
//= require gmaps/google
```

Here is the page supposed to render the map.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  buildMap (<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
</script>
```

And the associated coffee script is

```
class RichMarkerBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker #inherit from builtin builder
  #override create_marker method
  create_marker: ->
    options = _.extend @marker_options(), @rich_marker_options()
    @serviceObject = new RichMarker options #assign marker to @serviceObject

  rich_marker_options: ->
    marker = document.createElement("div")
    marker.setAttribute 'class', 'marker_container'
    marker.innerHTML = @args.title
    _.extend(@marker_options(), { content: marker })

  infobox: (boxText)->
    content: boxText
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
    boxStyle:
      width: "400px"

  # override method
  create_infowindow: ->
    return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow
    boxText = document.createElement("div")
    boxText.setAttribute("class", 'marker_info_box') #to customize
    boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
    @infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))

@buildMap = (markers)->
    handler = Gmaps.build 'Google', { builders: { Marker: RichMarkerBuilder} } #dependency injection

    #then standard use
    handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
      markers = handler.addMarkers(markers)
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers)
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
```

None of this code was recently changed (in the last week or so).
I only executed a bundle update today that upgraded the gems `jbuilder` from 2.4.1 to 2.5.0 and `autoprefixer` from `6.3.6.1` to `6.3.6.2`.
The app was working having the map rendered until now when the map is not shown anymore.
I reverted these two gems to the previous versions but still no map rendered.

Don't know how to make it working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the order of the scripts to be loaded and now the map is rendered again, here is the code:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&libraries=geometry;&key=AIzaSyAncOJnAgKEjrv2PY__Z0gYy3zJyTznUQ0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/gh-pages/src/richmarker-compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Problem solved.